# How can I make an REGEX that identifies a year between 1979 and 2024?

Tags: regex

I was tasked to make an REGEX that identifies an year between 1979 and 2024, where the year is located after 9 digits in a total of 20 numbers.

Example:
121212121**2009**2121212

I was trying to make it, but the only solution I found was near this code:

```
\b\d[0-9]{9}(19[7-9]\d|20[0-1][0-9]\d|202[0-4])\d[0-9]{7}\b
```

And it still doesn't work.

What did I miss?

Comment: `20[0-1][0-9]\d` describes 5 digits, not 4

Comment: Use `\d` OR `[0-9]` not both.... (`\b[0-9]{9}(19[7-9]|20[0-1][0-9]|202[0-4])[0-9]{7}\b` [see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NCEkBO/1), which is looking better )

Comment: When learning regular expression, you should keep it simple, like: `\b[0-9]{9}(1979|198[0-9]|199[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-9]|202[0-4])[0-9]{7}\b` (see: https://regex101.com/r/GDBIH9/1), making it complex, and possibly shorter, can always be done when you have more experience... , next step could be: `\b[0-9]{9}(1979|198[0-9]|199[0-9]|20[01][0-9]|202[0-4])[0-9]{7}\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b\d{9}(1979|19[89]\d|20[01]\d|202[0-4])\d{7}\b
```

Reads:

- `\b` word boundary
- `\d{9}` nine digits
- `(` start of capture group for year
- `1979` to handle the first case
- `|19[89]\d` any year in 1980 through 1999
- `|20[01]\d` any year from 2000 through 2019
- `|202[0-4]` the years 2020 through 2024, needs a dash because a range
- `)` end of capture group
- `\d{7}` seven digits
- `\b` word boundary